# How do you read this .wav file byte data?

Tags: python, audio, byte, wav

I used the python wave module and read the first frame from a .wav file and it returned this :

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What does each byte mean and will it be the same for every frame or for just some?

I've done some research into the subject and have found that there are bytes that give information about the .wav file in front of the sound data, so does python miss out this information and skip straight to the sound data or do I have to manually separate it?

There are 2 channels and a sample width of 3 according to python.

UPDATE
I have successfully created the waveform for the wav file, it wasn't as difficult as I first thought, now to show it whilst the song is playing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wave` module reads the header for you, which is why it can tell you how many channels there are, and what the sample width is.

Reading frames gives you direct access to the raw sample data, but because the WAV format is a bit of a mixed, confused beast it depends on the sample width and channel count how you need to interpret each frame. See [this article](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/wave.htm) for a good in-depth discussion on that.